# Setup static ipv6 address in /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: ip, ipv6, raspberrypi, static-ip

After changing to a new ISP last week I got a new IPV6 address at home. The IPV6 address is global so not just for my home connection. Because of this address my mail server isn't working properly anymore.

I'm wondering where I can find my 128bit global IPV6 address from my raspberry pi? The address doesn't show up in

```
ifconfig
```

and doesn't show up in my router settings. I'm assuming that the address changes every day just like the address on my windows pc.

Also I'm wondering assuming its changing every day how to make it static on my raspberry pi? Is this possible in

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

for example?

When trying to connect to my routers IPV6 address I always get the error:

```
Connection refused
```

So I'm pretty sure I have to use the global IPV6 address from my raspberry.

I hope someone can explain how IPV6 exactly works with mail servers and how to set it up again.

Thanks for reading/helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Enabling ipv6 on raspberry pi:**

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

Add "ipv6" at the end and reboot the pi2.

I'm assuming your new ISP giving you dynamic IPv6. you need to contact your ISP for static IPv6.

**Static ip on pi 2:**http://www.wikihow.com/Assign-an-IP-Address-on-a-Linux-Computer (remove DHCP with static ip)

your raspberry pi will get private IPv6 address from router(fd30:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx)

**Mail server:**

you need to use google ipv6 address DNS: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using

**Source:**

https: //www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=15886

http: //www.networkworld.com/article/2228449/microsoft-subnet/ipv6-addressing--subnets--private-addresses.html

Comment: Allright thanks! I'm gonna try those steps later today and tell you if it helped me further! :-)